# htaccess 301 subdomain moved

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect URLs like `http://www.site.gen.tr/index.php?ind=reviews&op=entry_view&iden=2381` to `http://arsiv.site.gen.tr?ind=reviews&op=entry_view&iden=2381` site.

I tried using .htaccess but could not make it work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this in your .htaccess file (need to be in domain root)

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 http://www.site.gen.tr/index.php?ind=reviews&op=entry_view&iden=2381 http://arsiv.site.gen.tr?ind=reviews&op=entry_view&iden=2381
```